# Navigating to a Page versus a View

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I am playing around with Xamarin.Forms (mvvm) with Prism and have noticed that [some tutorials](https://github.com/adrianhall/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/tree/master/Chapter3) show navigating to another Page while [others](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/tree/master/HamburgerMenu) show navigating to a View.

At a high level, I understand the literal difference... however I do not understand when I should use one over the other? I have an inclination that some of the reasoning is around dependencies, for example:

A Page has the instance of `User` > navigate to a view = `User` is still present when the `back` operation is used... meanwhile if you want this same behavior in navigating `to` and `from` a page, you'll need to pass the instance around via parameters... Is this correct/the reasoning behind navigating to and from `views` instead of `pages`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In X.Forms `View's` are only visual objects, they do not support any navigation or any kind of infrastructure. They can only be showed when you navigate to a `Page` that hosts them, it doest not make sense the phrasing navigate to a `View`. So you should only use `Page's`.. In your example project they also only navigate to `Page's`. In the one you say they are navigating to "Views" it is only in the name, because `ViewA` is a `ContentPage`

Answer (score 1):

Technically, in pure MVVM, the `ViewModel` should know completely nothing about the `View` and vice versa. When you use `Page First Navigation` approach you violate the first sentence. Here is an example:

```
class MyViewModel
{
}

class MyView
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Alternatively you can do the same thing in XAML
        this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

As you see the `View` is aware of the `ViewModel`.
When you use a `ViewModel First Navigation` approach, the decision of which 
 `View` should have witch `ViewModel` is delegated to a dedicated class. This class then is used in a custom `NavigationService` to match a `ViewModel` to a `View`. So it will be possible to navigate from a `ViewModel` to a `ViewModel`. This way both `ViewModel` and the `View` know nothing about each other.  The disadvantage of this approach is complexity.

This is a very short answer, however, I hope you will get the key point. There are many examples of both approaches:

- [ViewModel First Navigation](https://github.com/yuv4ik/iknowthatflag)
- [Page First Navigation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/#Performing_Navigation)

P.S.: Prism has very nice mechanism that handle navigation. What I wrote above and the examples that I provided are just for low level understanding of this approach. If you want to use Prism you definitely have to be familiar with it.